# Cell Phone Validation field using sms message

Tags: forms

I recently want to develop a field for user account.

The Field will provide a cellphone textfield and a validate button!

After finishing the cellphone textfield by the user, The user push the validate button.
[image]
Then, the system will send the sms message using ajax.

After sending the validate code message to the user, the system will respond the CODE to the client side. However, the cell phone textfield is invisible right now.

[image]

Finally,the user enter the code get from sms message and then push the button.

The system will check the code by ajax and then return the correct/false value to the client side.

After the steps above, the system will hide all the field and show the result of the validation.
[image]

My question is how can I do that?

Comment: You need to use some gateway to send SMS like http://support.clickatell.com/product_guides/clickatell_gateway.php

Comment: Thank you, i already have some api provided by the sms company. But i don't know how to achieve the function above!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to create this yourself. You want to use the relatively new [Two-Factor Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/tfa) Module and it's plugins -- or create your own plugin.

> Second-factor authentication for Drupal sites. Drupal provides
>   authentication via something you know -- a username and password while
>   TFA module adds a second step of authentication with a check for
>   something you have -- such as a code sent to (or generated by) your
>   mobile phone.
>
> TFA is a base module for providing two-factor authentication for your
>   Drupal site. As a base module, TFA handles the work of integrating
>   with Drupal, providing flexible and well tested interfaces to enable
>   your choice of various two-factor authentication solutions like
>   Time-based One Time Passwords (TOTP), SMS-delivered codes,
>   pre-generated codes, or integrations with third-party services like
>   Authy, Duo and others.
>
> Features
>
> - Pluggable - Supports multiple methods of 2nd factor verification and
>     can work with any number of 3rd party systems
> - Configurable - Supports fallback methods and context-specific exceptions
> - Flood control and even secures one-time logins
> - **Tested - Over 100 tests**
>
> TFA module is recommended as a full suite solution to 2nd factor authentication and Drupal.
>
> See the TFA basic plugins for a TOTP plugin that works with FreeOTP,
>   Google Authenticator, Authy, and any other app that works with TOTP
>   tokens.
>
> This module stores some sensitive data which it encrypts using the php
>   mcrypt library. You will need to have the mcrypt extension installed
>   to use the module.

This module is designed to allow you to meet your use-case (some custom code may be required). It's also designed with *fallbacks* and edge-cases taken into consideration which you may not have thought of -- and it has a zillion tests.

Answer (score 1):

[Mobile Number](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_number) module (that I wrote) does exactly that.

[image: field widget demonstration]

> Mobile Number is a field type that provides mobile number validation
>   and verification, and can be used for two factor authentication. It
>   works with SMS Framework and TFA modules, respectively, and both
>   features are optional.
>
> The module differs from the Phone module in that it puts security and
>   authenticity first, and focuses on mobile numbers which therefore
>   assumes sms and smartphone capabilities by the user.